# System.InvalidCastException when adding an entity DBSet<T>.Add()

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

**Updating with more information**

**I am using EF Core 2.0**

The entity is:

```
public class Vehicle
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string TenantId { get; set; }
 public string Make { get; set; }
 public string Model { get; set; }
 public string Year { get; set; }
 }
```

I have my mapping configuration as,

```
 public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Vehicle> builder)
 {
      builder.ToTable("Vehicles");
      builder.HasKey(field => field.Id);
      builder.Property(field => field.Make).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
      builder.Property(field => field.Model).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
 }
```

I configure the entity in DBContext using;

```
 DataContext.Set<T>();
```

And then if I perform any action against this DbSet it gives this error. Notice the highlighted parts. They are all identical.

System.InvalidCastException occurred
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=
  [A]**MyProject.Models.Vehicle** cannot be cast to 
  [B]**MyProject.Models.Vehicle**. Type A originates from 
  '**MyProject.Models., Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null**' in the context 'Default' at location 
  '**D:..\MyProject.Models.dll**'. 
  Type B originates from 
  '**MyProject.Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null**' in the context 'Default' at location 
  '**D:..\MyProject.Models.dll**'.

The only reference i could find related to above is 
[here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/cast-exception-when-i-am-trying-to-insert-an-entity-in-entity-framework-using-code-f/77673). In my case it doesn't seem to be the entity mapping config.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update 1:**

My Service class accepts type T which defines the entity it's going to work with such as;

```
public abstract class DomainService<T> : IDomainService where T : class, IEntity 
{ 
    protected DomainService(ApplicationDbContext context) 
    { 
        WorkingSet = context.Set<T>(); 
    } 
}
```

The auto property WorkingSet is now correctly setup for the entity T and I can confirm it in debugging. But performing anything with WorkingSet such as
WorkingSet.Add(dataentity) gives the error mentioned above.

But, if I hardcode the DbSet in context class like

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{
    public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

It works! If needed I can continue with this option but I would like to avoid hardcoding DbSet in context class.

Comment: Pleasse provide the code where you call the `DbSet<T>.Add()`

Comment: Using EF Core 2.0. Service class accepts <T> which defines what entity it's going to work with such as `public abstract class DomainService<T> : IDomainService where T : class, IEntity { protected DomainService(ApplicationDbContext context)
{  WorkingSet = context.Set<T>(); } }` I set the entity type in the constructor and using the exposed WorkingSet. So, doing `WorkingSet.Add(someT)` gave this error. But, hard coding the DbSet in context like `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>{public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicle { get; set; }}` It works!

Comment: So the point is I do not want to hard code the entities in DBContext every time a new entity is introduced. It should be possible to set it dynamically with Set<T> before start to work with the entity.